# Sqlite datetime aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Ребят,пишу своего игрового бота,и хотелось бы узнать,как добавить время в бота.Чтобы было на подобии этого:

```
Юзер:Бонус
Бот:Вы получили бонус 100 монет
Юзер:Бонус
Бот:Вы уже получили бонус,приходите через 23 часа.
```

Comment: можешь делать запись в базу данных с текущем времени в секундах (когда пользователь ПОЛУЧАЕТ бонус), потом просто когда пользователь хочет получить бонус, делай проверку (текущее время - то что находиться в бд, sql поддерживает команды)  https://www.mousedc.ru/learning/65-sql-select-where-like-and-or/

Comment: Но как именно делать запись в бд...